# docker pull: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

How do I give a new service account this permission?

I have a VM with "Compute Engine default service account" and it works.

I changed the service account to one with just:

```
Artifact Registry Administrator
Artifact Registry Reader
```

and this results in the above error on `docker pull`.

Thanks

Comment: can you also tell us where you are running the pull command this image? Is in a gcp vm or is it in some other machine ?

Comment: Also can you verify that you have authenticated to the GAR before pulling the image ? https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling

Comment: can you provide the error message that you get.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are correctly configured `Docker` to be able to pull and push images to `Artifact registry` : https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling

You also have to be sure you are using the expected Service Account in the place where you execute your command.

If you execute from you local machine and bash, check if you are connected on the expected Service Account with :

```bash
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=your_key_file_path.json

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=your_key_file_path.json
```

The permissions you given to you Service Account seems to be corrects to execute the needed action.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are trying to push/pull an image on a repository in which its specific hostname (associated with its repository location) is not yet added to the credential helper configuration for authentication.

For the [gcloud credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper) or [standalone credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#standalone-helper), the Artifact Registry hosts you use must be in your Docker configuration file.

Artifact Registry does not automatically add all registry hosts to the Docker configuration file. Docker response time is significantly slower when there is a large number of configured registries. To minimize the number of registries in the configuration file, you add the hosts that you need to the file

You need to configure-docker while impersonating your service account ($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL):

**1.** Run the following command to make sure you are still impersonating $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL:

```
   $ gcloud auth list
```

If the service account is not impersonated then run the following command:

```
   $ gcloud auth activate-service-account \ "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL" \ --key-file=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH
```

**2.** Run the configure-docker command against the auth group:

```
   $ gcloud auth configure-docker <location>-docker.pkg.dev
```

**3.** Finally, try pulling the Docker image again.

Refer [Authenticating to a repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#auth) and [stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72255017/15745153) for more information.